# forward outgoing port and sourcenat this traffic

Tags: iptables, port, forwarding

I have crawled the internet, and tried some config, but so far, i am stucked, so i would need a little help if someone has a better experience than me on this. :)

I got a server,server1, behind a proxy. proxy server holds 1 public IP and 1 internal IP.
I would like that connection from server1, in direction to specific host:port on the internet, go through the proxy, and be sourcenated. other traffic from server1 ( like for updates, are reaching the internet directly, without going through the proxy ).

Ex:

- from server1 , trying to reach http://myApidestination.tld:81/myAPI
- traffic is redirected to port 8080 on proxy
- proxy receives the traffic on port 8080, and forward to myApidestination.tld on port 81
- this traffic is sourcenated, so the destination webserver will reply to the proxy

What i have done:

on server1:

```
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp -d myApidestination.tld --dport 81 -j DNAT --to-destination proxy:8080
```

on proxy:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i INT_IF -o EXT_IF -p tcp --dport 8080 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i INT_IF  -o EXT_IF -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i EXT_IF -o INT_IF  -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i INT_IF -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination myApidestination.tld:81
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o EXT_IF -p tcp --dport 81 -d myApidestination.tld -j SNAT --to-source proxyPUBLIC_IP
```

forwarding is activated in kernel and module is loaded.

Traffic from server1 is going to proxy and arriving on port 8080, as expected.

But then, traffic never go through the proxy, and never quit this box. looks like the rules are not well written, and the paquets never delivered outside proxy.

Any idea please ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Yann

Answer (score 0):

First of all - you trying to route traffic in wiered manner.

On proxy with your rules:
packets dnated to 81 port in prerouting, then blocked in forward chain.

At least you should replace

*iptables -A FORWARD -i INT_IF -o EXT_IF -p tcp --dport **8080** -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT*

with

*iptables -A FORWARD -i INT_IF -o EXT_IF -p tcp --dport **81** -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT*

Also check routing table on proxy.

Consider diagram
https://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/chunkyhtml/images/tables_traverse.jpg

from
[Netfilter chains and tables traversing](https://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/chunkyhtml/c962.html)

Comment: Hi Gapsf
thanks a lot for the info, i have tried it, but was not sufficient to make it work. I got to search deeper. Your links were good explanation, thanks again for your help. still digging :)
would you have any other advise, that would be appreciated :)

Comment: I think now problem with backward traffic because you change dst port from 8080 to 81 - proxy receive packets on 81 port on EXT_IF, but not change it to 8080 in backward direction. Try to add another rule iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i IXT_IF -p tcp --dport 81 -j DNAT --to-destination server1 _ip:8080 Also **backward** traffic may blocked in forward chain - debug with tcpdump or -J TRACE target

Comment: For debugging you may use *conntrack* utility on proxy to list connections